# Print a list of names with function a sole argument

Tags: list, function, python-3.x, loops

I am writing a program that contains a list holding the names of four USA presidents. Use any presidents you wish. Then, run a loop that adds four more presidents to the list. Call another function with the list as its sole argument. This second function should sort the list and then loop through the list to print each president's name on its own line. I have some code done but it only prints the list of the first set of names. I can't figure out how to get the names sorted and print all the names entered in the list.

Here is my code:

```
president = 4

def main():

    names = [0] * president

    for pres in range(president):
        print('Enter the name of a president',sep='',end='')
        names[pres] = input()
        names.sort()
        print(names)


    for pres in range(president):
        print('Enter the name of another president',sep='',end='')
        names[pres] = input()


def names(name_list):
    name_list.sort()
    return name_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'pres' gets reset in the second loop at line 17 (it will loop over indices 0-3 and overwrite the previous 4 presidents). For a quick fix maybe try both `names[pres + 4] = input()` at line 17 and `names = [""] * 8` at line 6

Answer (score 0):

```
for pres in range(president):
    print('Enter the name of a president',sep='',end='')
    names[pres] = input()
    names.sort()
    print(names)
```

You don't need to do `names.sort()` every time you add a new president to it. If you want to add 4 presidents, then add it. Sorting is the last step, right?

In your second loop, you use the same index to add another president. This will change your elements in your list and you will still have 4 presidents, no more. My suggestion is to use

```
new_president = input()
names.append(new_president)
```

instead of

```
names[pres] = input()
```

Here is my full code:

```
def create_presidents(no_presidents=4):
    presidents = []
    for _ in range(no_presidents):
        presidents.append(input("Enter a name: "))
    # More presidents
    for _ in range(no_presidents):
        presidents.append(input("Enter another name: "))
    presidents.sort()
    return presidents

def print_presidents(presidents):
    for president in presidents:
        print(president)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    no_presidents = 4
    presidents = create_presidents(no_presidents)
    print_presidents(presidents)
```

Answer (score 0):

im even more confused than when i started now :(. Huy vo, i think 4 presidents names are supposed to be in the list by default then the user insputs and adds 4 others to that list then its supposed to display the list.